# Better move generator than brute force in Neutreeko

Tags: algorithm

I'm implementing a game called Neutreeko (5x5 board, 3 pawns for each of the two players) and for the Monte Carlo Tree search I'm implementing, I need a fast way to generate all possible moves for the pawns owned by the player. I store the board state in a one-dimensional array where each cell equals to 'player', 'cpu' or 0.

As for the rules, a move is valid if the pawn moves along the horizontal, vertical or diagonal line to the farthest point it can without hitting a wall or other pawn (which means that if you were hypothetically standing in the center of an empty board, you would only be allowed in the very corners and in the middle cells of each side adjacent to these sides, total 8 moves).

What is a better way of finding the moves than just brute-force travelling in each of the 8 directions until I hit a wall or other pawn? This also requires numerous conditions to assure that - when checking a diagonal - we don't accidentally go to the other line when travelling with the ascending indexes and so on. Of course it can be done but I bet there's some game theory practice which deals with it more elegantly and eficciently.

Comment: There's at least one idea here, http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Efficient+Generation+of+Sliding+Piece+Attacks, in the section called, "Sliding Attacks by Calculation."

Comment: @groovy - will surely check it out, thanks.

Comment: ...and if you read further below, there's the idea of pre-calculating all options - (2^5=32) possibilities for any one ray.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this is not completely unclear...

Each piece causes certain exclusions in the allowable moves, by blocking lines. There are 24 lines (10 + 14 diagonals) and by my count 320 possible sliding moves. It might be best to use 5 "wraparound" diagonals in each direction for a total of 20 lines and at most 20 moves on each. Every piece rests on either 3(corner) or 4 lines, and when a piece moves you update the line it moves along, and the 4-6 others which are affected.

The exclusions for a particular square, i.e. the moves that a piece on that square blocks, are constant. All you need to do is add or subtract a constant binary string from each line. To generate a new position, check some bit flags for each move from the squares of the player's three piece to see if the number of exclusions for that move is zero.

The maximum number of exclusions for each move varies (e.g. if an entire row is full, there are 5 reasons you can't slide from A to E). The total representation for a normal line is takes 23 bits.

ABCDE
AB,BC,CD,DE, AC, BD, CE need only 2 bits each (<=3 exclusions)
AD,BE,AE 3 bits

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Inspired by clwhisk's suggestion, I had the following idea:

Hash all board positions as 30 bits - first 15 bits as the computer's position, next 15 bits as the player's position (5 bits per pawn). For each 25 choose 3 (=2300) of the computer positions, generate the 22 choose 3 (=1540) matching player-positions, and set the hash to point to the next board positions (where the first 15 bits are the computer's pawns) that would result from a move by one of the computers pawns.

This way no moves would need to be generated nor winning positions tested. It seems like the hash size would be 2300 * 1540 = 3,542,000 but would include pre-calculated next-board-states for all three pawns at once, including hashed winning positions. Additionally, the board could be represented as one number, rather than having two bit-boards representing each player's position (as is common in some other board games).

Well, that idea crashed on my Firefox browser, even with a web worker. So my alternative idea would be to use the 2300-item hash as a key to a two-dimensional array (2300x2300; player_1_position x player_2_position), who's values are the board states that could follow player_1's available moves. Also, one could try to hash half the positions - if it's not in the hash, it's in the mirror position.

End update.

Here's a JavaScript example that attempts to hash all board positions, boards, and moves -- it seems to me that there are 25 choose 5 = 53130 possible states for the board (not including the pawn for which we would like moves for); and each board state offers 20 possible positions for our pawn to be placed on.

I'm not sure how the speed of looking up in this sizable hash might compare with generating available moves on the fly. Pre-calculating the hash takes a few seconds to load on the browser, as can be expected.

To look-up available moves, type: `hash[board<<5|position]`,

For example:

```
console.log(hash[31<<5|6])
[1048576,512,8388608]

console.log(hash[31<<5|7])
[2097152,512,32,16777216,1024]
```

JavaScript code (the functions,`comb` and `main`, are adapted from this [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#Lexicographic_ordered_generation) in C):

```
var hash = {}

function comb(m, n, c)
{
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) c[i] = n - i;

    while (1) {
        var s = 0
        for (i = n; i--;)
            s|=1<<c[i]-1;

        //hash boards, positions, and moves
        for (var j=1; j<=25; j++){
            var pos = 1 << (j - 1)
            if (pos & s)
                continue
            hash[(s<<5)|j] = moves(pos,s)
        }    

        /* this check is not strictly necessary, but if m is not close to n,
           it makes the whole thing quite a bit faster */
        if (c[i]++ < m) continue;

        for (i = 0; c[i] >= m - i;) if (++i >= n) return;
        for (c[i]++; i; i--) c[i-1] = c[i] + 1;
    }
}

function moves(position,board){
    var leftBorder = 17318416,
        rightBorder = 1082401,
        moves = [],
        positionTemp = position

    //up
    while (positionTemp < 1<<20 && !((positionTemp<<5) & board))
        positionTemp <<= 5

    if (positionTemp != position)
        moves.push(positionTemp)

    positionTemp = position

    //down
    while (positionTemp > 1<<4 && !((positionTemp>>5) & board))
        positionTemp >>= 5

    if (positionTemp != position)
        moves.push(positionTemp)

    positionTemp = position

    //left
    while (!((positionTemp<<1) & board)){
        if (positionTemp & leftBorder || positionTemp == 1<<24)
            break
        positionTemp <<= 1
    }

    if (positionTemp != position)
        moves.push(positionTemp)

    positionTemp = position

    //right
    while (!((positionTemp>>1) & board)){
        if (positionTemp & rightBorder || positionTemp == 1)
            break
        positionTemp >>= 1
    }

    if (positionTemp != position)
        moves.push(positionTemp)

    positionTemp = position

    //NW
    while (!((positionTemp<<6) & board)){
        if (positionTemp & leftBorder || positionTemp >= 1<<20)
            break
        positionTemp <<= 6
    }

    if (positionTemp != position)
        moves.push(positionTemp)

    positionTemp = position

    //NE
    while (!((positionTemp<<4) & board)){
        if (positionTemp & rightBorder  || positionTemp >= 1<<20)
            break
        positionTemp <<= 4
    }

    if (positionTemp != position)
        moves.push(positionTemp)

    positionTemp = position

    //SW
    while (!((positionTemp>>4) & board)){
        if (positionTemp & leftBorder || positionTemp <= 1<<4)
            break
        positionTemp >>= 4
    }

    if (positionTemp != position)
        moves.push(positionTemp)

    positionTemp = position

    //SE
    while (!((positionTemp>>6) & board)){
        if (positionTemp & rightBorder || positionTemp <= 1<<4)
            break
        positionTemp >>= 6
    }

    if (positionTemp != position)
        moves.push(positionTemp)

    return moves
}

function main()
{
    var buf = new Array(100);
    comb(25, 5, buf);
    console.log("done")
}


main()
```

Comment: Why not simply map all 25 choose 6 = 177100 board positions to (a pointer to a list of) the up to ~60 (and usually less) possible next positions? If you know the game is restricted to 5x5 simple is the way to go. The easiest format to identify a position is 25*24*23*22*21*(6 choose 3) = 127 million, which would take only megabytes, not gigabytes of memory.

Comment: @clwhisk thanks for the good idea -- how would you suggest the computer identify which of the next possible positions would be the result of a move by one of the computer's pawns?

Comment: If you're generating a table of all the movements up front, it doesn't matter so much, but my answer below might reduce the number of computations compared with something more straightforward to code. All it takes is a 32 bit integer or pointer to identify a position.

Comment: @clwhisk thanks for your comment. I still don't understand, if the computer could reference available `next` positions, how could it differentiate the ones that would follow a move by one of the computer's pawns? (regarding your own answer, I must admit I can't undersand it - could you add some illustrative examples to your answer?)

Comment: `int[][][] nextpos;//173million x 2 x n array [position number][player][<list of n position numbers that player can move to from this position>]`

Comment: @clwhisk `[position number]` does not tell you which of the six pawns in that position belong to `player`. Using your plan, it seems the list would have to point to both [position #] and [player]. No? In any case, your idea to hash next board states rather than available moves inspired me - see my update at the top of my answer.

Comment: It's easy to determine the position from it's number by dividing out 24*23*22*21*(6 choose 3) for the position of the first pawn, etc. If you've marked the winning states, this isn't necessary to solving by monte carlo until you want the gui to display the solution. And no, all it requires is toggling a boolean for whose turn it is.